# Possible to Customize Profile Page on Moodle without touching core?

Tags: php, moodle

Is there a way to customize the profile page in moodle without editing the core files? Is it possible to override the page and keep the edits within the theme files? similar to how overriding a renderer keeps all the edited render files inside of the theme folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I was trying to do by building a custom layout in my theme for mypublic.php, then inside this theme I included another php file that displayed all the attributes I wanted via global variables:

```
<?php
       echo '<div id="profilename" class="col-sm-6">';

        function get_content () {
        global $USER, $CFG, $SESSION, $COURSE;
        $wwwroot = '';
        $signup = '';}

        if (empty($CFG->loginhttps)) {
            $wwwroot = $CFG->wwwroot;
        } else {
            $wwwroot = str_replace("http://", "https://", $CFG->wwwroot);
        }


       if (!isloggedin() or isguestuser()) {
       echo '<a href="'.$CFG->wwwroot.'/login/index.php">'.get_string('loggedinnot').'</a>';
       echo '</div>';
       echo '</div>';

       } else {
        echo '<ul id="custom_profileinfo">';

        echo '<li><span>'.get_string('username').': </span>'.'<a href="'.$CFG->wwwroot.'/user/view.php?id='.$USER->id.'&amp;course='.$COURSE->id.'">'.$USER->username.'</a></li>';
        echo '<li><span>'.get_string('firstname').': </span>'.'<a href="'.$CFG->wwwroot.'/user/view.php?id='.$USER->id.'&amp;course='.$COURSE->id.'">'.$USER->firstname.'</a></li>';
        echo '<li><span>'.get_string('lastname').': </span>'.'<a href="'.$CFG->wwwroot.'/user/view.php?id='.$USER->id.'&amp;course='.$COURSE->id.'">'.$USER->lastname.'</a></li>';
        echo '<li><span>'.get_string('email').': </span>'.'<a href="'.$CFG->wwwroot.'/user/view.php?id='.$USER->id.'&amp;course='.$COURSE->id.'">'.$USER->email.'</a></li>';
        echo '<li><a class="edit_profile" href="'.$CFG->wwwroot.'/user/edit.php?id='.$USER->id.'&amp;course='.$COURSE->id.'">'.get_string('updatemyprofile').'</a></li>';
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
       }
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the the $CFG->customscripts setting to use a copy of profile.php :

create a customscripts folder

```
yourmoodlesite/customscripts
```

Then set

```
$CFG->customscripts = 'yourmoodlesite/customscripts';
```

Then create a user folder in customscripts and copy profile.php so you have

```
yourmoodlesite/customscripts/user/profile.php
```

and remove or comment out the require...config.php line.

Now Moodle will use /customscripts/user/profile.php when viewing a profile.

Have a look yourmoodlesite/config-dist.php for more details

Comment: Point of clarification: "yourmoodlesite" must be the absolute path to the Moodle site in question. For example "/home/myuser/public_html".

Comment: Also note that the config.php file indicates that customscripts should not include config.php.

Comment: Another trick that you can use in config.php is the following:
`$CFG->customscripts = dirname(__FILE__) . '/customscripts';`

That will ensure that your path to customscripts is always correct, since it starts with the base path where config.php is located.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you want to change. If it is field names, then you can override the language strings via the admin interface.

If it is adding new custom fields, then that can be done via admin > users.

If it is hiding fields, then that should be possible with some custom CSS rules.

Other than that, you probably need to do some custom core changes (or start messing around with the page layout using javascript, injected via the theme).

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. I want to change the layout completely, while displaying the student/user information. I have been able to do these complex layout overhauls by creating custom layouts and overriding the renderers all within my theme, but in order to edit the profile page it seems like I have to edit user/profile.php. I could edit the core but I would have to worry about updates to moodle  in the future ... not sure what to do from here :)

Comment: It is possible to maintain core modifications during upgrade by careful use of git, particularly using Tim Hunt's method for major version upgrades http://tjhunt.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/moving-ou-moodle-code-to-moodle-261.html . You are right that they are not ideal, but in this case there isn't an alternative I'm aware of.